# Daemogoth Titan as only creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Quick question about [Daemogoth Titan](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Daemogoth%20Titan) rulings. The text say:

> Whenever Daemogoth Titan attacks or blocks, sacrifice a creature.

Does this mean "whenever it attacks or blocks successfully" or rather "in order to declare it as attacker/blocker, you need to sacrifice a creature"?

When does the sacrifice take place exactly and what happens if it's my only creature in play?

Answer (score 6):

### Daemogoth Titan's ability is an triggered ability

You can tell because it begins with the words  "when" or "whenever".

Attaching or blocking with the Titan causes its ability to trigger. This trigger goes on the stack, and when it resolves you must sacrifice a creature.

If you have no creatures to sacrifice the ability will do nothing. However, Daemogoth Titan is a creature itself, so unless the Titan left play between when it attacked and when its ability resolved, there will always be at least one creature available to sacrifice - the Titan itself.  While this would generally defeat the purpose of attacking, any creature the Titan blocked would remain blocked, so there is some utility there. Also, other abilities that trigger off attacking or blocking will still trigger even if the Titan is sacrificed to its own ability.

Comment: activated -> triggered

Comment: @caleth whoops! Thanks for catching that.  It's far too early in the morning.

Answer (score 4):

> When does the sacrifice take place exactly and what happens if it's my only creature in play?

It is triggered in the declare attackers or the declare blockers step, after declaring it as an attacker or blocker respectively. The victim will be dead before damage is dealt.

If you are blocking, you can sacrifice a creature that has been declared as a blocker, and the opponent's creature is still blocked.

If it is your only creature, you'll have to sacrifice it to attack or block.

Answer (score 0):

The terms "attack" and "block" refer just to something being *declared* an attacker or blocker. All the other stuff, such as dealing and taking damage, and stopping a creature from dealing damage from a player, are results of attacking or blocking, they don't constitute attacking or blocking themselves. If you can somehow put Daemogoth Titan on the battlefield attacking, such with [[Fireflux Squad](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fireflux%20Squad)], you won't have to sacrifice a creature. If you manifest Daemogoth Titan, you can attack or block with it, then turn it face up at the beginning of damage assignment, and you won't have to sacrifice a creature.